# Can I use NSManagedObjectContext with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType in a concurrent GCD queue

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

My approach so far has been something like this:

- 1- A main context initialized like so:

  ```
  _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.model];
  if(![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
      DDLogModel(@"Unresolved error %@", error.localizedDescription);
      return;
  }

  self.context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
  self.context.persistentStoreCoordinator =_persistentStoreCoordinator;
  ```
- 2- Then, as I go about creating core data objects or modifying their relationships concurrently:

  ```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      NSManagedObjectContext *tempContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
  tempContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;

  //  Do stuff

  [tempContext save:nil];
  });
  ```
- 3- And finally, the main context merge via the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`

However, I've recently seen a different approach where for step 2, they instead create a context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, make it a child of the main context, and do any work by means of `-performBlock:`

Is this last approach concurrent by default (even without explicitly dispatching it as such)? Or what's the advantage over the approach I explained?

Another thing that threw me off is that even though the contexts have `parentContext` and `persistentStoreCoordinator` properties, it appears that setting the latter implies one cannot set the former. That is, a context with a persistent store coordinator actually has that store coordinator as it's parent context?

**UPDATE:**
Another interesting thing is that with the approach I described above (using GCD), everynow and then when I do `[tempContext save:]` I get a weird behaviour: No error is returned (assuming I do pass in an NSError object, unlike in the example), but if I set the generic Objective-C exception pointer on, the background thread does stop there, as if there was an exception. However, if I continue the app does not crash and keeps going and the main moc seems to be just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. `performBlock` will automatically perform the work in the background. In some cases it might make sense to use the current thread (main or background), in which case you can use `performBlockAndWait`. Using child contexts is the recommended approach.

I suppose your setup could work just as well. I guess the advantage of using a child context lies in a more structured approach of saving, i.e. "pushing up" saves into the parent context. Only the parent context will actually touch the persistent store, so this is better in terms of thread safety.

Your last question is not clear. A context can only have a context as its parent context, not a persistent store coordinator. However, what might be confusing you is that prior to iOS 5 there was only a "Parent Store", and with the introduction of child contexts it could be *replaced* optionally by a parent *context*. Read all about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-256616).

Comment: when you say that `performBlock` does work in the background, do you imply "concurrently"? Cause I take it as "background thread, potentially only preempted along with the main thread." That is, time slicing but still serially. If so, I'd think my approach would be faster since I am explicitly doing it concurrently. Also, my last question is cause I observed that if I create a context and assign it a persistent store coord., if I then try to assign it a parent context it tells me it already has one (but I only assigned it a store coord!).

Comment: Yes, I mean concurrently. The child context should be initialised with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` for this to work. The effect should be the same. Concurrency always works with time slicing unless you have multiple processors. -- For the PSC question, read my answer!

Comment: I have a couple more questions: does a moc with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType implictly create its own queue? Or do I still need to create it inside a GCD concurrent queue? Also, if a child pushes the changes to the parent and only the parent saves, wouldn't this mean that if I tell a child moc which is handling a single object to save, the parent ends up saving and so any other objects with pending changes in the parent moc would also save? Cause I'd want to only save the changes in the child moc

Comment: Another interesting thing is that with the approach I described above (using GCD), everynow and then when I do `[tempContext save:]` I get a weird behaviour: No error is returned (assuming I do pass in an NSError object, unlike in the example), but if I set the generic Objective-C exception pointer on, the background thread does stop there, as if there was an exception. However, if I continue the app does not crash and keeps going and the main moc seems to be just fine.

Comment: Actually, I've been testing `[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType]` and it never executes in a thread other than the main one. So it's not even concurrent :/

Comment: That does not sound right. Apple: "Private queue (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType): The context creates and manages a private queue." How did you verify this?

Comment: I know it doesn't sound right to me either :/ I confirmed both by stepping thru the active threads in the debugger and by logging `[NSThread currentThread]` both outside and inside the the `-perfromBlock` blocks. And it's always the same thread. In contrast, if I create concurrent GCD queue and dispatch with confinement (like in step 2 of my example), I can clearly see different threads executing. Also, just in case, 2 comments up I said that sometimes I'd get exceptions on background threads. This is no longer the case, it had to do with the merge policy.